# CI/CD pipeline for Magento 2 on AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, magento2, amazon-lightsail

I have a magento 2 instance on AWS lightsail which I am using for product hosting. Currently any changes in magento's theme , files are being pushed using ftp / sftp , but I would like to automate the process and use bitbucket / git and technologies similar to serverless for continuous deployment. I have searched throughout but could not find a good solution. Any help / idea would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance